# Extract Date Portion Only From DateTime Field

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2000

In `SQL Server 2008` I use this to take out only the date piece `Cast(field as date)`.  For example, if I use the below garbage DDL

```
  Create Table #Bbb
  (
    id int
    ,datetime1 datetime
  )

  Insert Into #Bbb Values
  ('1', '2016-03-01 17:35:19.000')
  ,('2','2016-03-01 18:44:15.000')
  ,('3','2016-03-05 18:58:05.000')
  ,('4','2016-03-05 19:52:27.000')
```

I run this query it will only give me the 2 rows where the date is equal to `03/01/2016`:

```
Select *
FROM #Bbb
WHERE CAST(datetime1 As Date) = '2016-03-01'
```

Now the question being, how would I do the same in a `SQL Server 2000` instance, since `Cast(datetime1 As Date)` does not exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check for the daily boundaries i.e. between the begining of the day at 00:00 and the begining of the next day at 00:00.

Query:

```
DECLARE @date datetime = '20160301'

SELECT *
FROM #Bbb
WHERE datetime1 >= @date AND datetime1 < DATEADD(day, 1, @date)
;
```

Or this `WHERE` clause for dates on a given day or later:

```
WHERE datetime1 >= @date
```

Output:

```
id  | datetime1
1   | 2016-03-01 17:35:19.000
2   | 2016-03-01 18:44:15.000
```

You can also remove the `TIME` part (set it to `00:00:00.000`) with this query:

```
DECLARE @date datetime = getdate()
SELECT @date, DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, @date), 0);
```

However using functions will limit index usage.

Ouput:

```
datetime                | date
2016-03-09 14:40:25.080 | 2016-03-09 00:00:00.000
```

Comment: that works perfectly for one day. What if I need to say  > '20160301' - how would I do that?

Comment: just remove the datetime1 < DATEADD(day, 1, @date) part ? @date is 2016-03-09 00:00:00.000 so just the > will work fine